# Injecting URI in ogm.properties from environment variable (spring data neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm, spring-cloud-config

Is there a way to inject URI in the `ogm.properties` (spring data neo4j) using environment variable ?

e.g. URI=http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474 works fine; however if I try this: `URI=http://${userid}:${pwd}@${hostName}:7474` and supply those as the environment variables does not work.

At runtime, spring data neo4j accesses the url as is without replacing the variable values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported. Please use the [Java configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_configuring_the_http_driver) instead of ogm.properties instead, then you're free to read environment variables.

Example:

```
@Bean
public Configuration getConfiguration() {
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config
       .driverConfiguration()
       .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
       .setURI(uri)
       .setCredentials(username,password);

   return config;
}
```

Comment: Just an update, mmaybe it works now : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_connecting_to_neo4j